# When I choose Library dependency, I can't find 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'

Tags: android, android-studio

When I want choose library dependency, I can't find

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1
```

But I just installed android version 23, 22 and 19. What should I do?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Comment: `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'`

Comment: I mean,I'm installed android 23,22,19version,so when i search library dependency i should find support -v7:23..or support-v7:22..and support-v7:19...but in choose library dependency I just find support-v7:24.0.0,and I don't installed android 24 version!